# Facebook Authentication for Website - Requirements for Application review process

Tags: facebook

When using Facebook authentication for a website, what are the requirements for the review process?

I assume that Facebook does not need a working version to test how you are using permissions such as posting, if you are not developing a Facebook app and merely using their Log-in plugin?

In addition to the Log-in plug-in, I am requesting the 'publish_actions' extended permission in order to post to the user's feed.

Thanks

Comment: So, what's your question basically?

Comment: Using login will not require review. But publish_actions you will have to get reviewed for

Comment: Apologies.. I realise what I was missing. Thanks for your time